# Pause simple fader script on mouse-hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like pause on hover when the mouse hovers over the fadelinks div for this script:

```
  $(function(){
  $('.fadelinks > :gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){$('.fadelinks > :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo
('.fadelinks');}, 5000);
});
```

The html is along the lines of:

```
<div class="fadelinks">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things relating to `interval` to try and cram pause on hover functionality in there, but with my extremely limited jquery knowledge, everything I've tried breaks the script, leaving it stuck on the last slide or the first slide. Would just like this simple script to pause on mouse-hover and start up again on mouse-exit.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccmgdfog/1/) of the script in its natural state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.hover()` , declaring variable to reference `setInterval` , using a function to call `setInterval`

```
$(function(){
  // define `_interval` variable
  var _interval;
  // cache `.fadelinks` element
  var elem = $(".fadelinks");
  elem.find("> :gt(0)").hide();
  elem.hover(function() {
    // "pause" at `hover` of `.fadelinks`
    clearInterval(_interval)    
  }, function() {
    // "reset"
    interval()   
  });
  var interval = function() {
  _interval = setInterval(function(){
                elem.find("> :first-child")
               .fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end()
               .appendTo(elem);
              }, 2000)
  };
  interval()

});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ccmgdfog/4/

Comment: That only seems to pause if the mouse is over the caption span at the top. It should pause on hover anywhere over the fader. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there wasn't the need for jQuery. Only with `stopInterval` you can control it. Altrough there is the jQuery `$.stop()` function, we wouldn't get the desired result.

I've changed a bit your code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadelinks > :gt(0)').hide();

    var interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 2000);


    $('.fadelinks').on('mouseenter',function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
    $('.fadelinks').on('mouseout',function(){
        interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 2000);
    });

    function intervalFunc(){
        $('.fadelinks > :first-child').fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadelinks');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. That was great code. It seemed to throw a strange flicker glitch in IE though if one hovered over the caption span for a few seconds. I appreciate the help and time though.